# Why do the positions of some texts look different in canvas and in postscript?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, postscript

Below is the screenshot that is taken when the program is running.

[image]

Below is the screenshot that is taken when the postscript file is run.

[image]

Why do the positions of some texts (`STANDARD PENETRATION TEST` and `GEOLOGICAL DESCRIPTION`) look different in program and in postscript? All of them are created with similar functions. I really didn't understand why this is happening?

By the way, below is the function that exports the canvas to the postscript file. I wonder whether or not position differences of some texts are related with a parameter of this function.

```
    def export_canvas(self):
        self.postscript(
            file="output.ps",
            colormode="color",
            height=self.canvasy(self.winfo_height()),
            width=self.canvasx(self.winfo_width())
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see three possible reasons;

Firstly that the PostScript program generated by the application does not match the intended result. That would be a bug in the PostScript generator.

Secondly, the PostScript interpreter you are using has a bug and is incorrectly rendering the PostScript program, leading to a different result. That would be a bug in the PostScript interpreter, you could test it by using a different PostScript interpreter. You don't say what you are using to render the PostScript.

Thirdly the display in the original application is incorrect. Something of a wild possibility, but the text looks centered in the PostScript rendered output, and doesn't in the screenshot, nor does it appear to be left justified. That makes me wonder if the text is intended to be centered in the white space, but the display is incorrect. Presumably you created this document so you would know which is the intended result.

There are other minor typographical differences between the two; for instance the 'Y' in LITHOLOGY intersects a table line in the screen shot, which it does not in the rendered version.

Presumably you know what the expected result is, so you can determine whether this is intended behaviour or not. You could try a different PostScript interpreter to see if it renders the PostScript program differently. If it does then it's most likely a bug in the PostScript interpreter you were first using. If it doesn't then it's a problem of some kind in the generating application, either in display or in creation of the PostScript. You can then open a bug report with the relevant maintainer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using the default PDF Viewer of Ubuntu to render the postscript file. I haven't tried other programs yet. The incorrect display of the original application is set like that by me, at first the texts had been positioned correctly but after I saw that even though they are positioned correctly, the positions of the mentioned texts in the postsript file were different. That's why I changed the positions in the original program in a way that they look correct in the postscript file.

Comment: PostScript isn't PDF. If you're using a PDF viewer then it must be first running something like Ghostscript to create a PDF file from the PostScript. Obviously that introduces another layer of uncertainty into the whole process. It sounds to me like the PostScript generation is incorrect, but its hard to know.

Comment: Ghostscript is installed on the computer. When I open the ps file with ghostscript the layout is not changing. I really don't know how to render a postscript that the texts look same as they look in canvas. By the way this strange behaviour is happening when the texts are inserted horizontally.

Comment: I'm not surprised that Ghostscript is rendering the PostScript the same as the PDF viewer, since the PDF viewer is almost certainly using Ghostscript to turn the PostScript program into a PDF file. You really need to try another PostScript interpreter to verify its not the PostScript program (perhaps you have access to a PostScript printer ?). But that said, it seems likely ot me that the problem is the PostScript generation, rather than the interpreter. So really this isn't a PostScript question, or bug, its whatever application is generating the PostScript and I can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I suspected too that it's an issue of `tkinter`.